# Cucumber plug-in installed but feature file opens in normal Text Editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, bdd, feature-file

I see cucumber installed under installed section of Eclipse marketplace. As I attempt to create feature file (eg, search.feature) I am getting a pop up window that displays how do you want to open this file directing me to pick a plug-in from marketplace or open using default Eclipse Text Editor and as I select Ok > marketplace opens but nothing displayed. I uninstalled and installed cucumber plugin > restarted eclipse but my feature file is being created as regular Text Editor.

Answer (score 0):

There was some kind of glitch in my eclipse I guess. None of the attempts from YouTube videos worked. So I deleted .eclipse folder, took backup of projects from workspaces and deleted all workspace folders including .metadata > Restart system > Download and Install Eclipse > Add cucumber plugin from marketplace. Boom, my new feature file opens not in text editor but in cucumber format.